# Is there a way to pass the same value to all arguments of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there's a way to pass a value to all arguments of a function without knowing the arguments available?

Example:

```
def SomeFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1)
    print(arg2)
    print(arg3)

SomeFunction("Hi"**)

>> Hi
>> Hi
>> Hi
```

The `**` in this case is just placeholder syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd never let this pass a code review, but for fun, why not?

```
import inspect
SomeFunction(*["Hi"] * len(inspect.signature(SomeFunction).parameters))
```

How does it work? Let's break it down.

You can use `func(*l)` to [unpack a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) into separate arguments, like so:

```
>>> SomeFunction(*['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi'])
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

[Multiplying a list by a number](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) duplicates the list that many times.

```
>>> ["Hi"] * 3
['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi']
>>> SomeFunction(*['Hi'] * 3)
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

Instead of hardcoding `3`, how can we get the number of arguments? Answer: The [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

```
>>> inspect.signature(SomeFunction)
<Signature (arg1, arg2, arg3)>
>>> inspect.signature(SomeFunction).parameters
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('arg1', <Parameter "arg1">), ('arg2', <Parameter "arg2">), ('arg3', <Parameter "arg3">)]))
>>> len(inspect.signature(SomeFunction).parameters)
3
```

Putting them together:

```
>>> ["Hi"] * len(inspect.signature(SomeFunction).parameters)
['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi']
>>> SomeFunction(*["Hi"] * len(inspect.signature(SomeFunction).parameters))
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

Comment: This is silly, and won't fail correctly in case of keyword-only args, *args or **kwargs.    –1